# Вопрос о запятой

Tags: запятая

Ув. филологи! Нужна ли запятая после "восстановленная"?
Восстановленная, кожа выглядит молодой и красивой.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь возможны два варианта написания:

А. Восстановленная кожа выглядит молодой и красивой (только определительное значение).

Б. Восстановленная, кожа выглядит молодой и красивой (определительное и обстоятельственное значение). В этом случае подчеркивается причинно-следственная связь:  кожа восстановленная - и  поэтому молодая и красивая.

Comment: Софья, спасибо за помощь!